# Condition problems in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements

I want to check 2 edittexts, if one of them is empty toast1 message will appear and if they are same toast2 will appear.
toast1 is working truly. but when they are same or different it shows toast1 it still says that one of them is empty
there are my codes. what need I do?

```
devamButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.devamButton);
    takimA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.takimAtext);
    takimB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.takimBtext);
    textTakimA = takimA.getText().toString();
    textTakimB = takimB.getText().toString();
    devamButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (textTakimB.isEmpty() || textTakimA.isEmpty()) {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"team name is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show();
            }
            else if (textTakimA.equals(textTakimB)) {
                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cant be same", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast2.show();
            }
            else {
                Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast3.show();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the text from the `EditText` when you're clicking the `devamButton` button and not before. Essentially move these lines:

```
textTakimA = takimA.getText().toString();
textTakimB = takimB.getText().toString();
```

inside the `onClick` method. That way you'll be getting the text that's inside the EditTexts right when you need it. As you have it, you're checking it before the user has even had the chance to input anything, hence both of them being empty.

Comment: thank you so much it worked! I am new at android studio you saved a lot of time thank you again!

Comment: @Akinci we all have to start from somewhere! Good luck with your project, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Because you have assign String object before click event fire. So when click it always take the old values.

Put those two lines in onClick event callbaack:

```
 textTakimA = takimA.getText().toString();
textTakimB = takimB.getText().toString();
```

Make it as:

```
devamButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.devamButton);
takimA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.takimAtext);
takimB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.takimBtext);

devamButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

textTakimA = takimA.getText().toString();
    textTakimB = takimB.getText().toString();

        if (textTakimB.isEmpty() || textTakimA.isEmpty()) {
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"team name is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show();
        }
        else if (textTakimA.equals(textTakimB)) {
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cant be same", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast2.show();
        }
        else {
            Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast3.show();
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked!
I am new at android studio
you saved a lot of time
thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I encounter a situation where a single button should have multiple functions depending on the condition. I do it this way:

```
devamButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.devamButton);
takimA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.takimAtext);
takimB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.takimBtext);
textTakimA = takimA.getText().toString();
textTakimB = takimB.getText().toString();

if (textTakimB.isEmpty() || textTakimA.isEmpty()) {
devamButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"team name is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

else if (textTakimA.equals(textTakimB) {
devamButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cant be same", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

else {
devamButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"no problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't defineit like this, because the text value in EditText always change on user input.

Comment: Obviously it will work, but just imagine what if user change the inut of textTakimA, and user click on button?

Comment: It seems to be doing what you need, but it's a very novice approach. It implies that you can't separate what setting a listener and what a callback method is. If a view needs a Listener, you set it after you create the view. If you want to control what happens when that listener is triggered, you add checks to the callback methods

Comment: you guys talking very good but i cant understand it seems I have to learn very much things
thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: @NileshB it will check the condition again and run as per the code...

Comment: @Akinci can you try copy pasting my code once and running it??

Comment: @Akinci when you set the OnClickListener to a view (eg. a button) you're essentially saying that you want that view to Listen for user clicks. You also define what's meant to happen when the user clicks on that view. Just because you write the method onClick inside the OnClickListener doesn't mean that it gets executed straight away. It is only executed (triggered, fired, etc) when the user clicks on that view.